# SQL Server : create logon trigger for failed logins

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to find a way to record failed logins to my server. I noticed that the logon trigger it fires only on succedded logins. Is there any way to fire a trigger when someone fails to login to my server?

- Microsoft SQL Server Express Version 15.0.2000.5
- Windows 10 Home

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I am trying to find a way to record failed logins to my server."* SQL Server already records that information in the logs; why duplicate existing functionality?

Comment: Only records this data. I know. With sp_readerrorlog or xp_readerrorlog i can retrieve them, BUT i cant find a way to capture the moment with a trigger. I want to reject users for same resons. For example, on 3 times with wrong password or massives attemps to login for some IPs from China( Maybe hackers, i traced 10 tries to login in 10s)

Comment: If you are constantly under "attack" from external IP addresses the real problem is that you have the SQL server open to access attempts from external sources and a lack of a white list on your firewall . Even if you *could* detect these login attempta with the trigger, SQL Server can't control the firewall rules on the server so would be unable to block them. This is a clear example of a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). Sort out your firewall rules.

Comment: Thnx for your thinking. I am thinking to list all devices with "trust device" auth like steam does for example via email. Is this a proper way?

Comment: At best, this question is going down a route that would be better asked on [sf].